# Google Analytics sees 3 url's when visiting 1 page

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics, analytics, google-tag-manager

When my form is filled in on the page: https://www.example.com/gratis-inspiratieboek/ it sends to the thanks page: https://www.example.com/gratis-inspiratieboek/balkonbeglazing-bedankt/

But in Google Analytics it shows 3 pages loading at the same time:
https://www.example.com/gratis-inspiratieboek/balkonbeglazing-bedankt/ and https://www.example.com/1/gratis-inspiratieboek/bedankt/ and https://www.example.com/gratis-inspiratieboek/bedankt/

But the url in the browser is only: https://www.example.com/gratis-inspiratieboek/balkonbeglazing-bedankt/ and there are no redirects on that page or one of the other pages.

Do you have any idea why Google Analytics sees 3 url's when filling in the form?
Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

After setup the proper Google Tag Manager, you need to follow below process to make sure that you did the proper configration of Google Analytics through the Tag Manager:

Go on the workspace, click new tag, enter the name of tag, click on Universal Analytics here you need to enter Tracking ID and Tracking Type as a pageview.

Now, click on the big icon where it says choose a trigger to make this tag fire and select all pages.

Completed.

You’ve successfully implemented Google Analytics with Google Tag Manager. Your Google Analytics tag will execute on every page.

Answer (score 0):

Your Google Tag Manager tags and triggers are configured improperly. There are too many triggers tied to different GA Pageview tags that fire on the same condition. This is why you have 3 pages recorded.